# Get Google Document as HTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I had a wild idea that I could build a website blog for an unsophisticated user friend using Google Drive Documents to back it.  I was able to create a contentService that compiles a list of documents.   However, I can't see a way to convert the document to HTML.   I know that Google can render documents in a web page, so I wondered if it was possible to get a rendered version for use in my content service.

Is this possible?

Comment: Note: You would think `DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getAs(MimeType.HTML)` would work, but that throws an error: `Converting from application/vnd.google-apps.document to text/html is not supported.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct method in GAS to get an HTML version of a doc and this is quite an old [enhancement request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=585) but the [workaround described originally](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/convert$20html/apps-script/gjEVtRd-kIo/rrRPCq4hRAQJ) by Henrique Abreu works pretty well, I use it all the time...

The only annoying thing in the authorization process that needs to be called from the script editor which makes it uneasy to use in a shared application (with "script unable" users) but this only happens once ;).

There is also a [Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20160122153346/https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice) created by [Romain Vialard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370762/romain-vialard) that makes things (a bit) easier... and adds a few other interesting functions.

Comment: i'd love to review the workaround you mentioned from @HenriqueAbreu but the link is no longer available: is it published elsewhere? -- Thanks, Fausto

Comment: Yes I know, they wiped out the archives ... anyway the code is still viewable in many places. This one for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954075/unexpected-exception-upon-serializing-continuation. And on the issue tracker as well.

Answer (score 32):

You can try this code :

```
  function getGoogleDocumentAsHTML(){
  var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId() ;
  var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); //needed to get Drive Scope requested
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+id+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  Logger.log(html);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Node.js Solution**

Using the [Google APIs Node.js Client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis)

Here's how you can get a google doc as html using google drive's node.js client library.

```
// import googleapis npm package
var google = require('googleapis');

// variables
var fileId = '<google drive doc file id>',
    accessToken = '<oauth access token>';

// oauth setup
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2,
    OAuth2Client = new OAuth2();

// set oauth credentials
OAuth2Client.setCredentials({access_token: accessToken});

// google drive setup
var drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth: OAuth2Client});

// download file as text/html
var buffers = [];
drive.files.export(
    {
        fileId: fileId,
        mimeType: 'text/html'
    }
)
    .on('error', function(err) {
        // handle error
    })
    .on('data', function(data) {
        buffers.push(data); // data is a buffer
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        var buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers),
            googleDocAsHtml = buffer.toString();
        console.log(googleDocAsHtml);
    });
```

Take a look at the [Google Drive V3 download docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents) for more languages and options.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this in python? Using the python client? https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client

Answer (score 6):

Google docs currently has a function to do this.
Just download to zip(.html) and you can have a zip archive with html & image (if inserted)

I know this is not solution based on code, but its working :)

[image: Menu for export]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a little snipped for the new version of goole AOuth following the    idea posted by Enrique:

```
function exportAsHTML(){
  var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); //needed to get Drive Scope requested
  var docID = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+docID+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  return html; 

}
```

and then use the usual mailApp:

```
function mailer(){
   var docbody = exportAsHTML();
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "email@mail.com",
     subject: "document emailer",
     htmlBody:  docbody  });
}
```

Hope the new workaround helps

JD

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem as well. The HTML that the Document HTML Export spits out is really ugly, so this was my solution:

```or-tag-here
/**
 * Takes in a Google Doc ID, gets that doc in HTML format, cleans up the markup, and returns the resulting HTML string.
 *
 * @param {string} the id of the google doc
 * @param {boolean} [useCaching] enable or disable caching. default true.
 * @return {string} the doc's body in html format
 */
function getContent(id, useCaching) {
  
  if (!id) {
    throw "Please call this API with a valid Google Doc ID";
  }
  
  if (useCaching == null) {
    useCaching = true;
  }
  
  if (typeof useCaching != "boolean") {
    throw "If you're going to specify useCaching, it must be boolean.";
  }
  
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var cached = cache.get(id); // see if we have a cached version of our parsed html
  if (cached && useCaching) {
    var html = cached;
    Logger.log("Pulling doc html from cache...");
  } else {
    
    Logger.log("Grabbing and parsing fresh html from the doc...");
    
    try {
      var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    } catch (err) {
      throw "Please call this API with a valid Google Doc ID. " + err.message;
    }
    
    var docName = doc.getName();
    
    var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); // needed to get Drive Scope requested in ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=" + id + "&exportFormat=html";
    var param = {
      method: "get",
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions:true,
    };
    
    var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param).getContentText();
    
    // nuke the whole head section, including the stylesheet and meta tag
    html = html.replace(/<head>.*<\/head>/, '');
    // remove almost all html attributes
    html = html.replace(/ (id|class|style|start|colspan|rowspan)="[^"]*"/g, '');
    // remove all of the spans, as well as the outer html and body
    html = html.replace(/<(span|\/span|body|\/body|html|\/html)>/g, '');
    // clearly the superior way of denoting line breaks
    html = html.replace(/<br>/g, '<br />');
    
    cache.put(id, html, 900) // cache doc contents for 15 minutes, in case we get a lot of requests
    
  }
  
  Logger.log(html);
  
  return html;
  
}
```

https://gist.github.com/leoherzog/cc229d14a89e6327336177bb07ac2980

Answer (score 1):

You may use the solution [here](https://ctrlq.org/code/19768-send-google-document-html-email)

```
/**
 * Converts a file to HTML. The Advanced Drive service must be enabled to use
 * this function.
 */
function convertToHtml(fileId) {
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId);
  var htmlExportLink = file.exportLinks['text/html'];
  if (!htmlExportLink) {
    throw 'File cannot be converted to HTML.';
  }
  var oAuthToken = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(htmlExportLink, {
    headers:{
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + oAuthToken
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  });
  if (!response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
    throw 'Error converting to HTML: ' + response.getContentText();
  }
  return response.getContentText();
}
```

Pass as fileId, the id of the google doc and to enable advanced drive services follow the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced).

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps this would work for you...

```
function doGet() {
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('myFileId').getAsHTML();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(blob);
}
```

Comment: Did you reference Romain Vialard's library ? if it is the case you should mention it in your comment