# Google Apps Script MailApp use document for htmlBody

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a simple document/template I would like to use when sending email to user. It works fine for text version, but I am unable to figure out, how to send the document in HTML format. The document only includes text with some bold formatting.

```
function sendEmail(emailAddress, attachment){
    var EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID = "SOME_GOOGLE_DOC_ID";
    var emailTemplate = DocumentApp.openById(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Subject", emailTemplate.getText(), {  
        htmlBody: emailTemplate, <-- THIS does not return correct data  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer I found is this one

```
function getDocAsHtml(docId){ 
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id=';
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+docId).getContentText();
}
```

works pretty well

Comment: If you get a 401, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663852/get-google-document-as-html)

Answer (score 0):

The `htmlBody` parameter expects a string while `emailTemplate` variable is of type Document.

You should use something like

```
 MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Subject", emailTemplate.getText(), {  
        htmlBody: emailTemplate.getBody().getText()  });
```

Comment: The formating in the htmlBody is completely lost (it is received as simple string). 

This is how the template looks (Simple text with italics, bold and enters): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IkJhOVCTs66F_4LJwMtmx0EM_QkNkunYYiHqT1MCwTw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly straight-forward if we take advantage of Roman Vialard's DriveApp library. You will need to follow the instructions [here](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice) to add the library to your project, and then you can use the code below.

```
/**
 * get a String containing the contents of the given document as HTML.
 * Uses DriveApp library, key Mi-n8njGmTTPutNPEIaArGOVJ5jnXUK_T.
 *
 * @param {String} docID ID of a Google Document
 *
 * @returns {String} Content of document, rendered in HTML.
 *
 * @see https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/driveservice
 */
function getDocAsHTML(docID) {
  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(docID);
  var html = doc.file.content.src;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(html);
  var template = response.getContentText();

  return template;
}

function sendEmail(emailAddress, attachment){
    var EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID = 'SOME_GOOGLE_DOC_ID';
    var emailTemplate = getDocAsHTML(EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, "Subject", emailTemplate.getText(), {  
        htmlBody: emailTemplate });
}
```