# get google doc as HTML in google app script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs

How can I get google doc as HTML in google app script?
For example. I can get document body like so.

```
DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
```

But when I log it there is nothing.

Comment: Try opening the document by its id: DocumentApp.openById("<my-id>");

Answer (score 10):

```
function doc_to_html()
{
 var id = document_Id;
 var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+id+"&exportFormat=html";
 var param = 
        {
          method      : "get",
          headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
          muteHttpExceptions:true,
        };
 var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, was looking for something like this to start off of but didn't think it was possible based on different answers in different questions. Works great!

Comment: If you're getting a 401 unauthorized error when trying to use this script, you can call `DriveApp.getRootFolder()` to have it [ask for the correct permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50038967/35690). Actually this snippet is very similar to [the one from the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503601/35690), and that one has a very similar line to make sure the 401 doesn't happen.