# Authentication issue with Google Apps Script deployed as a web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am facing HTTP 401 errors while trying to call a deployed Apps Script (as a web app, accessible to "anyone") from a second GAS with UrlFetch and a bearer in authorization header. The scripts were working fine for months until around two weeks ago.
Here are two small scripts to reproduce the error.

**Script A - Deployed as a web app, accessible to "Anyone".**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var params = e.parameter.params;
  console.info("Parameters : " + JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success");
}
```

**Script B - Calling the script A via UrlFetch**

```
function callURL() {
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    followRedirects : true,
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/<script_A_deployed_url>/exec?param1=test";
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param);
  if(resp.getContentText() != "Success"){
    console.info(resp.getContentText());
    throw resp.getContentText();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried doing the same using Postman/etc ?

Comment: Yes, I managed to reproduce this behavior using Insomnia.

Comment: What's the exact error message ? Earlier same setup & code was workin ?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized. Yes, we have been using this authentication mechanism since several months without any issue.

Comment: Try publishing app with public access (Anyopne, even anonymous) see if that works, if that works, then make sure header is coming properly

Comment: With public access, callURL() is working as expected with and without the authorization header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) pointed me in the right direction. Apparently, some internal rules recently changed in the authentication mechanism for Apps Script deployed as a web app.
For B script, the default scope with UrlFetch is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`, but it looks like we now need **at least read access to A script**, which means we also need Drive scopes. 
In order to achieve that, you can for example have this function in B script to authorize them.

```
function setScope() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Can you confirm the following points again?

1. For the client side, are there some functions except for your script of the client side in the project? If there is only the script in the project, the scope for accessing to Web Apps is not enough. The scopes for Drive API are required to be included in the scope of access token.

   - You can see the current scopes at File -> Project properties -> Scopes.
   - For example, those are the following scopes.

     - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`
     - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`
     - `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`
2. In my log, when `Who has access to the app:` is installed as `Anyone`, I confirmed that from April 11, 2018, it is required to be shared the project to access to Web Apps. This might be due to the update of Google.

   - Please share the project of Web Apps with users and try again.
3. For the Web Apps server side, if you set `User accessing the web app` for `Execute the app as:`, please authorize the scopes using own browser. This authorization is required to do only one time.

If these were not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks ! You point me in the right direction. It seems that now, script B needs the Drive scopes and at least reading rights on script A to avoid 401 errors. I will clarify this in a new answer.

Comment: @Q_C Welcome. Recently, I summarized about Web Apps. If this is useful for you, I'm glad. https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, the file permission should be  `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` and not `...../drive.files`. I get an error with 'files', but 'file' works

Comment: @doWhileTrue Thank you for your comment. I couldn't notice it. I could modify it. Thank you.