# Script can't access the Google-Apps-Script web-app

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm Creating a Google Spreadsheet where I Use a Google Apps Script WebApp to add rows to a protected sheet.
To Access the WebApp I'm using the UrlFetchApp, see code below:

```
var url = "https://script.google.com/a/domainname/macros/s/AKfycbz6WkbXo4eY2VvZ63358RA-n____________jxkPS/exec";
var query = "?usermail=" + Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
var url = url+query;
var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(request).setWidth(900).setHeight(800), "info");
```

When I use the url in my web browser, I get a success and the row is added in my sheet (the authorization is set I presume).
But when I use the Sheet to run above script I need to login into google:

link of the modal Dialog:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/2MdQRJo7gxTBtyMu6

After entering a valid email-address I get the error:
accounts.google.com refused to connect.

What is causing this error?
I've also set all the files (Sheet and scripts) to shared by link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Send a `Authorization` header

Comment: You have a `doGet(e)` function that is triggered when a GET request is made to the published URL of the Web App.  You should probably have a `doPost(e)` function also, and make a POST request instead of a GET request.  `doGet()` is basically used mostly for serving HTML to the browser.  That's not what you are doing.  How is the Web App published?  You can publish it as "anyone, even anonymous" can run the code.  There are two settings:  "Execute the app as:" and "Who has access to the app:"  Those settings determine whether the requesting source needs to log in or not.

Comment: @TheMaster, I'll look into the authorization header, I used the 'basic' authorization, but since it's authenticated through domain it didn't work.

Comment: @SandyGood I have a doGet function on the web app. When i call it through Webbrowser, I have a reply that it works, but when i call it through the script it doesn't work, i get the image as shown.

Comment: `Authorization: "Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50021631/authentication-issue-with-google-apps-script-deployed-as-a-web-app) post has all the answers you seek. I would implement authorization as done by Q_C and Tanaike pretty much clarifies the remaining queries.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, Code is working now with Authorization : Bearer added, Also helpfull the post you added @JackBrown, you need to authorize the drive root folder for people to access the script!