# Using Google Apps Script HTML file (from sheets) as a template for a google DOC

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs

What I am trying to do is use an HTML file (that exists within Apps Scripts of a Google sheet) to populate the body of an auto generated Doc.

Process goes like this:

1. Drop down menu in sheets > click button
2. Scripts locates a Doc template with no body content > copies it, renames it, saves it to the same folder that the template is in
3. Closes the Doc.

I can't figure out how to populate the Doc body with the HTML file.

This is what I have right now: (htmlTemplate() is called when drop down button in sheets is clicked)

My HTML file is called practice-template.HTML

```
function htmlTemplate() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetTemplate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('template')
  var DOC_ID = '1I5q7BnAdj-KcF10Q6N9TgemMZt0Vkq15ipUfhA_iJTI'

  // opens Doc Template in Drive
  // var template = DocumentApp.openById(DOC_ID)

  // open in Docs when you're saving/creating a new doc
  var temploc = DriveApp.getFileById(DOC_ID);


  var dataRange = sheetTemplate.getRange('A1:H1').getValues();
  //get data from cells
  for (i in dataRange) {
    var rowData = dataRange[i]
    var dataOne = rowData[0]
    var dataTwo = rowData[1]
    var dataThree = rowData[2]
  }

   // Get ID of Active sheet
  var ssloc = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId());
 
  // Get root directory of active workbook
  var ssfolder = ssloc.getParents().next();

  // makes a new google doc based on the template and named appropriately, in the same folder as the template
  var newcopy = temploc.makeCopy(dataOne,ssfolder);
  var newcopyurl = newcopy.getUrl();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(newcopyurl);

  var docBody = doc.getBody()

  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('practice-template')

  var data = {
    data_one: dataOne,
    data_two: dataTwo,
    data_three: dataThree,
  }
  htmlBody.data = data;
  var content = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent();
  
  docBody.replaceText("{{body}}",content)
  doc.saveAndClose()
}
```

When I run the above code I get a new google Doc in the appropriate folder, and the document is populated with the HTML from the practice-html.html file. The problem is that the text in the new google doc is in html syntax and not plain text.

The google Doc template file only has {{body}} as content.

Comment: In your script, `htmlBody.evaluate()` returns `HtmlOutput` object. If you want to use the HTML of text, please modify `var content = htmlBody.evaluate().getContent()`. But, in your showing script, `sheetTemplate` is not declared. So, I think that your script occurs an error at `var dataRange = sheetTemplate.getRange('A1:H1').getValues();`. So, from `I get an error message about docBody.replaceText(content)`, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script for correctly replicating your current issue. How about this?

Comment: And also, about `htmlBody.data = data`, in this case, can you provide your HTML `practice-template`? By the way, your goal is to put the HTML data (unrendered raw HTML text data) into Google Document. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have made some progress and edited my question to reflect where I am at with this. Does this clarify things at all?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question is using [DocumentApp.Body.replaceText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) but it passed only one parameter while this method requires two, both parameters should be string. By the way, the `content` variable have assigned a `HtmlOutput` object, not a string.

You could use HTML to create a file in Google Drive, then convert that file to Google Docs format, but it's very likely that the best approach is to use a Google document as template, or if you need to create the content programmatically, then use Documents Service (Class DocumentApp), the Advanced Google Docs Service or the Google Docs API.

Related

- [Render HTML to a Google Doc using app script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044843/1595451)
- [Importing a HTML table into a google doc using google app script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35688581/1595451)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm still struggling with this. It does not appear to me that Documents Service or the Advanced Documents Service will help me to solve my problem. I have looked into the Google Docs API and there is quite a lot to learn in order to use it. I don't want to spend time learning that if it won't help me solve my problem. Any idea if it will help me to render HTML to a newly created Google Doc? Thanks