# How to send rich text emails with GmailApp?

Tags: google-apps-script

I’m trying to send a Google Doc, with all of its formatting, in an email.

```
function sendGoogleDocInEmail() {

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById("example_Id");
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var text = body.getText();

  GmailApp.sendEmail("emailaddress@gmail.com", "Hi", text);
```

This code works fine, but the email is sent as plain text.

I have descriptive hyperlink text pieces in the Google Doc, and they lose their hyperlinks when converted to plain text.

Is there any way I can keep all of the hypertext formatting when sending the email?

I’ve tried passing the body object to the method instead, but that just sends an email with `DocumentBodySection` in the body.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying using a combination of this script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503601/3520117

And then using the htmlBody parameter of the MailApp.sendEmail method.

Untested, but should work:

```
function emailGoogleDoc(){
  var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId() ;
  var forDriveScope = DriveApp.getStorageUsed(); //needed to get Drive Scope requested
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id="+id+"&exportFormat=html";
  var param = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions:true,
  };
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText();
  Logger.log(html);

  var email = person@domain.tld;  
  var subject = 'Subject line';
  var body = "To view this email, please enable html in your email client.";

  MailApp.sendEmail(
    email,           // recipient
    subject,         // subject 
    body, {          // body
      htmlBody: html // advanced options
    }
  );
}
```