# Monitor click events on bookmarks (Google Apps Script)

Tags: events, google-apps-script, onclick, click, bookmarks

Is there a way to **monitor click events on bookmarks** in google documents with google apps script? I want to **get bookmark id when someone selects a bookmark** and than run some more code which needs that bookmark id to get processed.

Comment: You cannot capture click events in Google Apps Script. You would need to use a web app and the HTML Service with client side JavaScript to do that.

Comment: Can you provide an example maybe?

Comment: Web Apps through GAS are [well documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). Essentially, you use GAS as server-side scripting and then JavaScript/HTML as the client side interaction.

Comment: Ok I'm not sure I'm doing it the right way but, I created a sidebar in a *.html file and include javscript with a click event listener. The script works, but it works only inside the sidebar. I want it to work inside the Google Document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Brian Bennett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2278429/brian-bennett)'s help I managed to solve this issue with [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). There is a little bit more code to write but it works.

1. Write a doGet function:

doGet function is called when a user visits your Web App. With doGet function I opened a document with ID given through get parameters and displayed it as html. To get a html of the document I used [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28503601/5068563).

2. Find and display bookmarks:

You can find bookmarks in the html of the document as html  tag with id of the bookmark. I changed the css of all this  tags so I could see them (change background, height, width or something like that).

3. listen to click events on bookmarks with jquery or just javascript:

Listen to click events on those  tags (bookmakrs) with jquery or javascript. If you use jquery, you need to import a jquery library. When click event happens get the id of the bookmark from the id attribute of the  tag.

4. Use that bookmark id as you wish...