# Get a copy of Body to make a "preview" window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm basically doing a mail-merge (replacing `Total: $ {total_amount}` for `Total: $ 20.00`) in a Google Docs document with Google App Script.

However, I want a `preview` option, where I show a modal dialog or something, and then I append to it a copy of the `Body` of the actual document. That way I can replace all the variables and keeping the original format (bold, italics, etc).

I already have an implementation that loads the current document as HTML exported and appends it to the dialog.

```
html = getGoogleDocumentAsHTML();
replaced = replace(html);

output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(replaced)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setWidth(700)
  .setHeight(500);

DocumentApp.getUi().showModalDialog(output, 'Preview');

/*
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663852/get-google-document-as-html#answer-28503601
 */
function getGoogleDocumentAsHTML(){ ...
```

But with this approach I am unable to show the pages, so that the user knows the paragraphs that fits on each page, layout, etc.

Is there any way to get a copy of the `Document`'s `Body` to do this, or a similar approach?

Comment: You can create temp copy the working doc, modify it as requested by the user. Embed the modified temp doc itself in a model dialog. Then remove the temp document when the user makes the choice. The embedded doc will retain all the page numbering and layout.

Comment: @SpencerEaston can you provide an example as the answer, please?

Comment: @ChristopherFansisco which part? Copying, modified, and deleting a document is pretty straight forward.  Do need a snipped showing how to embed the doc in a dialog box?

Comment: @SpencerEaston correct. Embedding a document in the dialog. You might want to include what you said in the first comment so that other people may also consider your approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a copy of the active document.
2) Make changes to this copy of the document.
3) Embed the changed document in a dialog box.
4) After user is done previewing the new document, delete the modified copy.

You can display a document in a dialog box using an iframe. Dialog sizes of course can be changed from the example below. The the important part is `https://docs.google.com/document/d/{id}/preview?authuser=0`. I tacked the `authuser=0` to give the hint to use the current users credentials. This isn't necessary, but it can prevent the account chooser box for popping up.

code.gs

```
function renderDocument(docId){      
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('dialog');
  html.ID = id
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
   ui.showModalDialog(html.evaluate().setWidth(800).setHeight(910), "html") 
}
```

dialog.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe frameborder="0" style="width:90%;height:900px" allowfullscreen="" src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/<?=ID?>/preview?authuser=0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```