# output google document as html using google doc api

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

Is it possible to export google doc in HTML format using google doc API? The only option that I found on their website is to output document contents as JSON. I'm creating an online tool that requires me to retrieve the content from google doc and keep the same style/format, so I need the HTML version.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Google Document as HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663852/get-google-document-as-html)