# Event duplication?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm facing a strange issue with a Google Spreadsheet Script on GAS.

Sometimes a function, triggered by the event "mouse up" below, is executed two or three times with a difference of seconds between each running. It doesn't happen every time, the problem looks pretty much random.

Button:

```
var button = app.createButton("Alocar").addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)).addMouseUpHandler(app.createServerHandler("onAllocateTask").addCallbackElement(panel));
```

"onAllocateTask" beginning:

```
function onAllocateTaskSheet(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.toast("Aguarde alguns minutos.", "Atenção", 8);

  var task = e.parameter[TASK_ALLOCATION_PARAMETER];
  if (task == null || task == "") {
    return;
  }

  ... continues ...
}
```

I can **guarantee** the function "onAllocateTaskSheet" is called just **once** in the code (on the piece of code above). Another important information is that this procedure (onAllocateTaskSheet) has a high execution time (it copies dozens of Google Docs documents).

Is there a explanation for a duplicated execution of this function? Perhaps I'm using the wrong event? Some internal error can cause the procedure to be reexecuted?

Thanks again for helping!

EDIT:

Ok, now  I can confirm the problem is not related with the button or the event mouseUp. The problem is the function "onAllocateTask" being reexecuted after X minutes. It does not happen when onAllocateTask finishes quickly (in less than 1 minute for example). I guess it related with some timeout or internal error.

[Unexpected exception upon serializing continuation Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947708/unexpected-exception-upon-serializing-continuation-google-apps-script)
Here someone says something about Google Apps Scripts losing the "loop pointer". Could it be possible?

Comment: As I said in my answer I don't have a clear explanation but I also noticed that this re-execution happened when the function takes too much time to execute... The lock 'trick' solved the issue completely for me. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Sergeinsas I tried it yesterday and the problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to that :-)  I use it on every long and slow operations and it solves the problem every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any good explanation on this but it happened to me too. The best solution is to use the lock service that will guarantee that only one instance of a function will be executed on one click.
It is very easy to implement :

at the begin of your function get a lock like this :

```
  ...
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  var success = lock.tryLock(5000);
   if (!success) {
     Logger.log('tryLock failed to get the lock');
     return
   }
```

and at the end of normal execution release the lock like this :

```
   lock.releaseLock();
```

(taken [from documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock?hl=en))

Comment: such a hack can lead to very strange behaivour. You should at least use a PrivateLock to mitigate the side effects. Hovever this does not solve the problem as the code reexecution is only postponed.

Comment: I did assume that the button was disabled on first click with a clientHandler because that's what I use. Nevertheless it still happens that the server function tries to execute a second time without any click and the lock solution rejects that... it doesn't postpone. what kind of strange behavior do you think about ?

Comment: aquiring a lock does not prevent the server function to run a second time without a click - you have to release the lock sometimes and even the private lock is script global. If you **really** have the button firing events while being disabled - what i don't really believe you can set a flag in a hidden field with a client handler to prevent execution:

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem is a button firing events while disabled (actually in my opinion it would be a bug, even with me using distinct events like mouseUp and click). Anyway I will try the lock solution, thank you.

Comment: `var hidden=app.createHidden('flag','go'); var clienthandler = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false).forTargets(hidden).setValue('stop')` in the handler you just test 'if (e.parameter.flag = 'go')`

Comment: Thank you again Taras. I've edited my original post, turns out the problem it's not related to the button. I guess the public lock solution can work for me, considering only a single user have access to the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the button on the clent side while your server request is running. But you should definitely use **the same event for the server and the client handler**.

```
var button = app.createButton("Alocar");
button.addClickHandler(app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false));
button.addClickHandler(app.createServerHandler("onAllocateTask").addCallbackElement(panel));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try to use the same events (currently I'm using onMouseUp for triggering the function and onClick to disable the button), although I think it isn't the problem. Sometimes the second execution starts after 1 minute, with the button already disabled :/